# Vert.x Redis Question About IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: redis, vert.x

I encountered a problem when using the Redis client of the vert.x , I would frequently update Redis when the concurrency was high, but an exception was reported

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: null
    at io.vertx.redis.client.impl.ArrayQueue.offer(ArrayQueue.java:56) 
    at io.vertx.redis.client.impl.RedisClient.lambda$send$10(RedisClient.java:257) 
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:366)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$executeAsync$0(EventLoopContext.java:38) 
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) 
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) 
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497) 
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) 
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) 
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

The version I use is vertx-redis-client: 3.8.5,and my code is:

```
 redisApi.hset(getList("key724762801283102234",sn,status) ,result ->{
      if(result.succeeded()){
        logger.info("success);
      }else {
        logger.error("failed");
      }
    });
```

So is there any problem here? thank you very much

Comment: This is an older version that is no longer maintained. Can you try with 4.0.0 or 3.9.5?

Comment: OK，I will try it

Comment: Everything is work well after upgrading to 4.0